# How to mount an existing react app to my webpage

Tags: html, reactjs

I have this [website](https://medium.com/oli-systems/react-todo-app-tutorial-e935fe716179) that I've deployed on Github pages. It has a home page that has 3 buttons each linking to a subpage. I also made a React todo app by following this [guide](https://medium.com/oli-systems/react-todo-app-tutorial-e935fe716179). I want to mount this react app to one of the subpages, projects.html, but the react app doesn't mount--projects.html shows blank white page when launching it with Live Server.

Here's my attempt...

1. Copied App.js, App.css, index.js from the built react app into a folder /react-todo-app beside projects.html

[image]

2. Added necessary script and div tags to projects.html

   Document

   ```
    <!-- To load React add the scripts. -->
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>

    <script src="/react-todo-app/index.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/react-todo-app/App.js"></script> -->
   ```

`/react-todo-app/index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The above steps are what ChatGPT and Google recommend. What else is missing?

Comment: How did you build them? – The files endings look like you copied the files from your source code not the built version.

Comment: @webwelten you're right those files are from source. I realize now I haven't actually built the app. After running npm run build, which files/folders should I copy beside the html file?

Comment: What are you using to build the project? Usually, it creates a build folder with files that you can link in your html.